# How are questions effectively reopened on SR?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

It requires 3000 reputation to [cast close and reopen votes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Looking at the [all time top user list](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we only have 14 users who could cast a reopen vote (at the time of writing).

Are these enough users to effectively reopen questions? If not, should I flag it for moderator attention, use the chat or do nothing?

Comment: It'll take ~1.5 more years for me to get that privilege, even though I'm on place 23. It's a bit sad.

Comment: Don't be sad (or else you'll always be sad for the next privilege). You're well over half way there, keep up answering questions and you'll get there sooner than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having participated as a 3000+ user, Yes. I have participated in quite a few reopen and close voting polls and it seems even after the final graduation of the site, the community (with help of our moderators don't forget) are able to to handle the load quite easily.

For now, keep using the Flag-> Close Question and a 3000+ user and/or moderator will be able to take further action.

[image: Flag to close a question]

Comment: Agree. Don't forget we mods also have access to the review queues :) In rare cases / occasionally (if you have the feeling it takes too long, or 12 out of those 14 users are on vacation, I personally don't have a problem processing a flag or following a ping, though.

Comment: Ok, closing is fine. I've seen that and I'm flagging. How about reopening?

Comment: Um, for reopening - I'd say ask for a reopen in the SR Chatroom, does that sound right @Izzy?

Comment: @Tom Yupp, that's fine as well – maybe even better than a flag: Usually, at least one of us mods is around there – plus a few others who might at least throw some things around... ahem... reopen-votes I mean :)

Answer (score 3):

We've [closed questions 656 times](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/502771) , and [reopened 186 times](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/502769) (~28%) not including deleted. Note that this may double-count cases where a question was closed and/or reopened multiple times; those should be negligibly rare.

Seems reasonable.